# How to add a view on top of keyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have added a view with buttons on top of keyboard using `setInputAccessoryView`. 
Now i want functionality like when i click button from the view i want to display a *pickerView* on top of keyboard. Means like adding *pickerView* as subview of keyboard.

How can i do this?

Comment: do you have any examples of apps that do this?

Answer (score 19):

Make a view you want to at the top of the keyboard. You can do this from xib or manually, but I think xib will be a better option.

Then make the reference to this view by doing this

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
   textField.inputAccessoryView = YOURCustomView;
   return YES;
}
```

Whenever you want to hide this or remove this just put this

```
textField.inputAccessoryView = nil;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
self.pickerContainerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 194, 320, 224)];
    self.pickerContainerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pickerContainerView];

    UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

    self.lblPickerViewTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 7, 230, 30)];
        self.lblPickerViewTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.lblPickerViewTitle  setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:17]];
        self.lblPickerViewTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        self.lblPickerViewTitle.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
    [pickerToolbar addSubview:self.lblPickerViewTitle];

    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];
    [flexSpace release];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(closePickerView:)];
    [barItems addObject:btnCancel];
    [btnCancel release];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"ShowPicker" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(donePickerView:)];
    [barItems addObject:btnDone];
    [btnDone release];

    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
    [barItems release];
    [self.pickerContainerView addSubview:pickerToolbar];
```

And in **ShowPicker** Method , write code for display UIPicker

Comment: My problem is i can able to add pickerView as subView of my view but key board is hiding that. so what i want when i click the button i want to display the picker view on top of keyboard.

Comment: ur problem is keyboard is not display and u wn to display pickerview on ur keyboed ??? m i right??

Comment: I have added a view on top of keyboard. that view has buttons. when i click a button i want to display a picker view in place of keyboard. but the problem is that view is added to the keyboard. so if you hide the keyboard that buttons view will also be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another UIWindow first:

```
UIWindow *newWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,320,20)];
newWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar; // this will make to place your WINDOW above the keyboard
[newWindow makeKeyAndVisible]; // show the new window

// [newWindow addSubview:yourView];
```

Comment: `UIWindow *newWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 250, 320, 200)];
    newWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
    [newWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
    [newWindow addSubview:self.myView];`             But it's not Working.

Answer (score 1):

like add button on keyboard you can also add view like bellow...

here you find window of keyboard and then set frame of button and also yourView and then add to keyboard

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification 
                                               object:nil];
    return YES;
}
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    UIButton *returnBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    returnBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0,-25,320,25);
    returnBtn.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    returnBtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
    returnBtn.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [returnBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"keyBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [returnBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(keyboardBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // locate keyboard view
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView* keyboard;
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        // keyboard found, add the button
        if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
            //  if (txtTag==5) {
            [keyboard addSubview:returnBtn];
    }
}
-(IBAction)keyboardBtn:(id)sender{
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView* keyboard;
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        // keyboard found, add the button
        if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
            //  if (txtTag==5) {
            [keyboard addSubview:yourView];// here add your view with frame
    }
}
```

i hope this help you...

:)

Answer (score 0):

From Jonas Schnelli's answer

```
UIWindow *newWindow = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,320,20)];
newWindow.windowLevel = CGFLOAT_MAX; // this will make to place your WINDOW above the keyboard

[newWindow addSubview:yourView];
```

Just change `UIWindowLevelStatusBar` to `CGFLOAT_MAX` will be ok.